# receiving details from POST

Tags: c#, cookies, post

im trying to build a program that can "login" to site as user to get the html code,
then ill fix the code to make more options to the user:)

i googled it and as i understand i need to send a cookie to identify myself as the user,
i use firefox edit cookies to see which cookies saves at my cmputer and saw only one 'phpsessid' that saves a string represent the session ,
i use wireshark to see how its real going and as i saw when im getting the response page im getting also this line

```
PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; path=/
```

how i can read it from the response string to be able surf another pages as the 'user'?

tyvm for your help:)

edit:
i got it:

```
Req.GetResponse().Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
```

Comment: if you found the solution pls post it as complete answer. with code sample and little description. it will help some one else in future.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do the login, create a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) and assign it to the request:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

After you make the request, `cookies` will contain the cookies that make you logged-in.

When you want to make another request, now as a logged-in user, use `cookies` again:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(anotherUrl);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```